# Change Tags and Classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a quiz app that users can choose their own predefined questions and answers but I need to change HTML tags and classes.

I have tried using jQuery replaceWith methods and removeClass addClass functions but it is just not working. Can anyone help please. Below is an example of my code:

The user clicks on a span element to answer the question, then the next question appears.

HTML code in Quiz Page:

```
<p id='question1' class = "quizQuestions">What element would I be? 
    <span>Water</span>
    <span>Earth</span>
    <span class="correctAnswer">Fire</span>
    <span>Wind</span>
</p>
```

Javascript for keeping score:

```
var questionNumber = 1;
var score = 0;
function showQuestion(question) {
    $('p').hide();
        if ($("p:nth-of-type(" + question + ")").length>0){
            $("p:nth-of-type(" + question + ")").show();
    } else {
        $("#final").show(); //this shows the player the score at the end
    }
}

$('span').click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("correctAnswer")) {
    score++;
}

$('.score').html(score);
    questionNumber++;
    showQuestion(questionNumber);
});

showQuestion(questionNumber);
```

I have a different section of code for the user to choose their own predefined questions and choose a predefined answer. Due to JS function problems I have had to change the tag names of the elements to prevent function errors. Below is an example of my code for users to choose their own questions.

HTML code in Question Option to choose from:

```
<ul id = "questionChoice1">If I were an animal, what would it be?
    <li>Horse</li> //The user clicks on li which add's Class "correct"
    <li>Bird</li>
    <li>Fish</li>
    <li>Bear</li>
</ul>
Now pick your correct answer & click Save
<button class="Save">Save</button>
```

Javascript for adding class to chosen answer:

```
$('li').click(function(){
    $('li').removeClass("correct");
    $(this).addClass("correct");
}); // this gives the span elements the class the user chooses
```

When the user chooses their li answer to questionChoice and clicks the Save button I need question1 in the main quiz section to become this:

```
<p id = "question1">If I were an animal, what would it be?
    <span class = "correct">Horse</span> 
    <span>Bird</span>
    <span>Fish</span>
    <span>Bear</span>
</p>
```

This is the last hurdle I need to overcome to complete my project. I just do not know how to change tag names...any help would be most appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: where is your javascript?

Comment: JS added @RajaprabhuAravindasamy thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is some useful javascript library named 'TweenLite'. Useing TweenLite you can change everything in html including tags and classes.

Here is the website:

http://greensock.com/tweenlite